# Pass a nullable parameter using jquery .ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have a following situation

```
function Insert(name, parentID) {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "topic.aspx/Insert",
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    "name": name,
                    "parentID": undefined
                }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {


                },
                error: function (msg) { alert(msg.responseText); }


            });
            }
```

And C# looks like this

```
[WebMethod]
        public static int Insert(string name, int? parentID)
        {
            GM.KnowledgeBase.Business.Topics topics = new GM.KnowledgeBase.Business.Topics();
            return topics.Insert(name, parentID);
        }
```

When parentID is null or undefined I get "Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter". Is there a more elegant way to solve this issue other then passing a parameter as a string and detecting if string is empty?

Comment: Don't pass the parameter at all?

Comment: Good idea, but the param is not passed if it is null. JSON.stringify does not include it in json output. So the solution is in modifying input params in C# for method Insert().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't pass it when it's not defined?

```
function Insert(name, parentID) {

    var data = { name: name };

    if(parentID)
        data.parentID = parentID

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "topic.aspx/Insert",
            data: data,
            // etc...
       });
}
```

or if your webmethod can parse `null`, this should do:

```
data: JSON.stringify({
    "name": name,
    "parentID": parentID || null
}),
```

Comment: it will be expected. maybe creating override method without parendID? is that what you are saying?

Comment: @John Since it's nullable, try my latter example.

Comment: Actually when value is null, JSON.stringify will not include this param in json output. So the solution is to create additional c# method something like public static int Insert(string name). This works

Comment: @John JSON.stringify inclues properties with null values. `console.log(JSON.stringify({ "name": 'blah', "parentID":  null }));`

Comment: try console.log(JSON.stringify({ "name": 'blah', "parentID":  undefined})); i think it is up to jquery version

Comment: @John It has nothing to do with jQuery - it's the `window` API. Also, if you look at my latest example, it will never be `undefined`. You will either get `null` or whatever value you set.

Answer (score 0):

Since you declared the parameter as nullable (in Insert function) you can safely do not send it from ajax function

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "topic.aspx/Insert",
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    "name": name

                }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {


                },
                error: function (msg) { alert(msg.responseText); }


            });
            }
```

After this you'll see a null value in Insert function for parentID parameter